# I am trying to get data from MongoDB field by field into my Java Code

Tags: java, database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

My Collection in MongoDB somewhat looks like

**_id |  Name  | Contact**

**101 | Justin |9999999999**

and I am trying to get these values in a String in such a way that is should be like

**101Justin9999999999**

in my java program but instead, all I can get is

**[Document{{_id=101.0, Name=Justin, Contact=9999999999}}]**

The code that I have tried so far is as follows :

```
public static void main( String args[] ) { 

    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 ); 

    MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("assingment");  

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("mongoData");

    FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find(); 

    String temp="";
    Iterator it = iterDoc.iterator(); 

    while (it.hasNext()) {  
        mongoArrayList.add(it.next().toString()); 
    }
  System.out.println(mongoArrayList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. When fetching data from your mongo database you'll get a collection of `Document` objects. You have to provide logic where you . iterate to the collection and build the desired string yourself, based on the field values.

Within each document you can do something like: `document.getString("Name")`, where `Name` is one of your column names in your mongo db.

Example code:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
  Document nextDocument = (Document) it.next();
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.append(nextDocument.getString("_id")).append(nextDocument.getString("Name")).append(nextDocument.getString("Contact")); 
  mongoArrayList.add(builder.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nazeem, did some changes in my code and it worked.